# Two Columns Come in one Column In oracle

Tags: oracle11g

What i Want in Coding is Delaysubreasoncode come under delayreasontable when i run the query. and Delaysubreason table should come like this 1C,2B, and so on Thanks in Advance. and i'm using Oracle SQL Developer adn both tables have their on description so i need description as well

Need all subreason code and subreason info come under reasoncode and reasoninfo wen i run the query

[Sample Table Image][1]

qUERY

```
Expected   Description
1           Rani
2           Fly
3           airline
4           train
5            bus
6            car
7            cycle
8            road
1C            rani off
2B             fly plane
3M              Birtish airline
4T            midland trains
5F             bus route
```

Comment: Can you show some expected results?

Comment: why not? now you can see the expected result

Comment: I've removed the tSQL tag, as this only applies to Microsoft SQL Server.  Can you show us your query?  We can then help you get it working.

Comment: ITS DATA protected so i Can't share here ...

Comment: “In a dark place we find ourselves, and a little more knowledge lights our way.”

– Yoda

Comment: Please put the table structure and same data into the question as plain text, not an image. You also haven't shown where the descriptions are coming from - it may be a trivial union but it isn't clear at all.

Comment: aDDED... please now i think its enough information i provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join the two tables; you can UNION queries against each one:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.reasoncode) AS reasoncode, dr.reasoninfo
FROM delayreason dr
UNION ALL
SELECT dsr.reasoncode ||''|| dsr.reasonsubcode, dsr.reasonsubinfo
FROM delaysubreason dsr;
```

The `TO_CHAR()` is needed to make the data types match - otherwise it will error with ORA-01790 when it see a number from the first query and a string from the second. You could also `CAST()` to varchar2, or concatenate which is less clear.